# isearch-forward-regexp key binding using Ctrl+Alt+s

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

The key binding for `isearch-forward-regexp` is `C-M-s`, however I cannot invoke that bindings somehow using `Ctrl+Alt+s`. I can do `Esc` then `C-s` to invoke it though.

Other commands with the `C-M` prefix works fine using `Ctrl+Alt` though, like `C-M-w` (`append-next-kill`), `C-M-f` (`forward-sexp`) etc

Can anybody an idea on what the problem on my system is? I am using `GNU Emacs 23.3.1` on `Ubuntu 11.10`.

Comment: What does Emacs tell you is bound to when you type: `C-h k C-M-s`?

Comment: It doesn't respond, I still have the "Describe key:" prompt in the minibuffer after pressing Ctrl+Alt+s.

I can see what Ctrl+Alt+w is bound to though.

Comment: That leads me to believe that the window system is not passing that event to Emacs.  I'd ask the same question on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem, and google is failing me...

Comment: As Trey Jackson indicated, C-M-s was a keyboard shortcut for my operating system and everything worked well after disabling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu 11.10, and on Ubuntu 12.04, the "toggle shaded state" keyboard shortcut is assigned to `Ctrl+Alt+S` by default. Changing it to something else enables the usage of that keybinding inside Emacs.

Comment: Where can I change the binding?

Comment: nvm in 12.10 found it under Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts